# Reset previous screen upon changing screen or clicking on a button

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

For my game, I would like to to reset a screen when the user changes screen.

I have tried many things such as using the Clock and making a update function, but it never really work. The layout does not change even though I explicitly change it in python.

For example, if I have button that becomes disabled upon release, when I change screen, it should not be disabled anymore This something that has been on my mind for a long time and don't quite get it.

I have three small files for this main.py, screen_manager.kv and main.kv. Sorry for this noob question

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

# Setup the window
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
width = 550
height = 550
Window.size = (width, height)

class OptionWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Quiz(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Quiz, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def update(self, dt):
        pass

kv = Builder.load_file('screen_manager.kv')
class Application(App):
    CATEGORY = ''
    def build(self):
        game = Quiz()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return kv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().run()
```

**screen_manager.kv**

```
# File name: screen_manager.kv
#:include main.kv
WindowManager:
    OptionWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<OptionWindow>:
    name: 'first'
    Button:
        text: "Reset SecondWindow"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = 'second'
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

<SecondWindow>:
    name: 'second'
    Quiz:
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        pos: 0, 0
        Button:
            text: "Go back"
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.4, 'y': 0.2}
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.6
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'first'
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

**main.kv**

```
<Quiz>:
    FloatLayout:
        id: thelayout
        size: root.width, root.height
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            text: 'press me'
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.2}
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
            on_release: self.disabled = True
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Your code provides for disabling the `Button`, but there is nothing in your code to re-enable it. Once a `Button` is disabled, it stays that way until something changes changes it. You can add something to your `SecondWindow` to re-enable the `button` every time the `SecondWindow` is displayed. You can use `on_enter` or `on_pre_enter` to trigger something to happen whenever that `Screen` is displayed. like this:

```
<SecondWindow>:
    name: 'second'
    on_pre_enter: quiz.ids.butt.disabled = False
    Quiz:
        id: quiz
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        pos: 0, 0
        Button:
            text: "Go back"
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.4, 'y': 0.2}
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.6
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'first'
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Note the added `id` for the `Quiz` and the added `on_pre_enter:`. Also needed is a way to reference the `Button`. I have done that by adding an `id` to that `Button`:

```
<Quiz>:
    FloatLayout:
        id: thelayout
        size: root.width, root.height
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            id: butt
            text: 'press me'
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.2}
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
            on_release: self.disabled = True
```

Now, everytime before the `SecondWindow` is displayed, the `on_pre_enter:` is triggered, and the `Button`` is re-enabled.